# Common custom toolbar for several different arcgis desktop addins using C#

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net, add-in

Suppose, I have two  arcgis desktop add ins C1Addin and C2Addin developed in c# with the following components:

C1Addin:
 Button_1

C2Addin:
  Button_2

When the 1st addin which may be any of the two addins is installed, it will create a toolbar and add the UI components of the corresponding addin to the toolbar. When the other addin is installed, it will add its components to that toolbar.

I have several problems to implement the above behavior:

1. How can I override the default initialization behavior of addin so that I can check whether the toolbar exists and if not I can dynamically create the toolbar?
2. How can a toolbar is uniquely identified by two or more addins?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question, but also, can you include a code snippet to illustrate what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?